# Are calculated/derived fields fully supported in Pony ORM?

Tags: python, orm, ponyorm

Suppose I have the following schema in [Pony ORM](http://ponyorm.com/):

```
from pony.orm import *

db = Database("postgres", database='foo')

class Job(db.Entity):

    job_id = PrimaryKey(int, auto=True)
    job_name = Required(str)
    base_salary = Required(int)
    multiplier = Required(int, default=1000)
    people = Set(lambda: Person)

class Person(db.Entity):

    person_id = PrimaryKey(int, auto=True)
    name = Required(str)
    job = Required(lambda: Job)
    experience = Required(int)
```

I would like the `Person` entity to have a `salary` attribute that's equal to:

```
Job.base_salary + (Person.experience * Job.multiplier)
```

My first thought was to add a property to the Person entity like so:

```
@property
def salary(self):
    return self.job.base_salary + (self.experience * self.job.multiplier)
```

This works for a simple query:

```
j1 = Job(job_name = "Astronaut", base_salary = 80000, multiplier = 5000)
j2 = Job(job_name = "Butcher", base_salary = 40000, multiplier = 2000)
j3 = Job(job_name = "Chef", base_salary = 30000)

for i, name in enumerate(["Alice", "Bob", "Carol"]):
    p = Person(name = name, job=j1, experience = i)

for i, name in enumerate(["Dave", "Erin"]):
    p = Person(name = name, job=j2, experience = i)

for i, name in enumerate(["Frank", "Gwen"]):
    p = Person(name = name, job=j3, experience = i)

for p in select(p for p in Person):
    print p.name, p.experience, p.salary
```

Prints:

```
Alice 2 90000
Bob 4 100000
Carol 6 110000
Dave 2 44000
Erin 4 48000
Frank 2 32000
Gwen 4 34000
```

But if I try something like this:

```
for j in select((j.job_name, avg(j.people.salary)) for j in Job):
    print j
```

Perhaps unsurprisingly, I get:

```
AttributeError: j.people.salary
```

since `salary` isn't a "real" attribute.  Is there a way to do this kind of thing that would allow calculated fields to be treated as first-class entities that can have normal aggregation / calculations done on them?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the suggestion!

Currently (Feb 2015) Pony ORM does not support calculated fields, but this feature can be implemented relatively easily, because Pony already have the ability to [translate lambdas to SQL](https://docs.ponyorm.org/api_reference.html#Query.filter). I hope we can add calculated fields soon.

Comment: Cool, looking forward to it!

Comment: I've added a [request](https://github.com/ponyorm/pony/issues/577) for this on the Pony Github.